# How to extract all text between certain characters with Python re

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

I'm trying to extract all text between certain characters but my current code simply returns an empty list. Each row has a long text string that looks like this:

```
"[{'index': 0, 'spent_transaction_hash': '4b3e9741022d4', 'spent_output_index': 68, 'script_asm': '3045022100e9e2280f5e6d965ced44', 'value': Decimal('381094.000000000')}\n {'index': 1, 'spent_transaction_hash': '0cfbd8591a3423', 'spent_output_index': 2, 'script_asm': '3045022100a', 'value': Decimal('3790496.000000000')}]"
```

I just need the values for "spent_transaction_hash". For example, I'd like to create a new column that has a list of ['4b3e9741022d4', '0cfbd8591a3423']. I'm trying to extract the values between 'spent_transaction_hash': and the comma. Here's my current code:

```
my_list = []

for row in df['column']:
    value = re.findall(r'''spent_transaction_hash'\: \(\[\'(.*?)\'\]''', row)
    my_list.append(value)
```

This code simply returns a blank list. Could anyone please tell me which part of my code is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is what you're looking for? `'spent_transaction_hash'\: '([a-z0-9]+)'`

Test: https://regex101.com/r/cnviyS/1

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you already have a list of Python `dict` objects, but in string format, why not just `eval` it and grab the desired keys? of course with that approach you don't need the regex matching, which is what the question had asked.

```py
from decimal import Decimal

v = """\
[{'index': 0, 'spent_transaction_hash': '4b3e9741022d4', 'spent_output_index': 68, 'script_asm': '3045022100e9e2280f5e6d965ced44', 'value': Decimal('381094.000000000')}\n {'index': 1, 'spent_transaction_hash': '0cfbd8591a3423', 'spent_output_index': 2, 'script_asm': '3045022100a', 'value': Decimal('3790496.000000000')}]\
"""

L = eval(v.replace('\n', ','))
hashes = [e['spent_transaction_hash'] for e in L]

print(hashes)
# ['4b3e9741022d4', '0cfbd8591a3423']
```